# Error in grep(pattern, x) : invalid regular expression '#Renewables (wind and', reason 'Missing ')''

Tags: r, string

I do not know why, given

```
> pattern
  [1] "#Renewables (wind and"
```

this simple code

```
x<-"#Renewables (wind and #solar combined with storage) are a"
grep(pattern,x)
```

produces an error like this:

```
Error in grep(pattern, x) : 
  invalid regular expression '#Renewables (wind and', reason 'Missing ')''
```

Comment: `(` is a special character in RegEx. You need to use `"#Renewables \\(wind and"`.

Comment: @MartinGal thank you. But I read, automatically, the text pattern from a file. How could I manage the problem in this case?

Comment: Depending on the special characters in your patterns, you should do a search and replace first: `gsub("\\(", "\\\\\\(", pattern)`

Comment: I added in grep, the argument fixed=TRUE

Comment: That's actually a better solution!